# Azure Function fails to load CRON timer from settings

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function written in C# and deployed as pre-compiled using Zip deploy directly from Visual Studio. Although on local everything works the function throws an error upon starting

> Function (RunStatsRecalculation) Error: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'RunStatsRecalculation'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: '%TimerInterval%' does not resolve to a value.

The CRON expression for timer setting is stored in the settings under key *TimerInterval* with value *"0 0 0 * * *"*

The function is defined as follows

```
    [FunctionName("RunStatsRecalculation")]
    public static async Task Run(
        [TimerTrigger("%TimerInterval%")]TimerInfo myTimer,
        ILogger logger,
        ExecutionContext context,
        CancellationToken ct)
    {
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can repro your issue. To resolve the issue, please add the key(TimerInterval) and value(0 0 0 * * *) to azure function application settings.

Here is my code:

```
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([TimerTrigger("%TimerSchedule%")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
            log.LogInformation($"this is a test for timer trigger...");
        }
```

And application settings:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've added it to the wrong settings. Works perfectly now.